# About to graduate and looking for full-time IT job; how to mention my internships experience on my resume?

Tags: job-search, internship, skills

I'm about to finish my computer science degree and I'm looking for a full time job in IT

During my time in the university, I took 3 different internship jobs - 2 as a full stack web developer and 1 as home automation programmer.

To which skill level should I apply? Should I put 3 years experience in my resume?

Answer (score 2):

> To which skill level should i apply?

First decide what role and position you want (full stack, home automation, or something else you really like).

Then, I would suggest you focus on *Junior positions*, as you are just finishing your degree and it's more likely/adequate to land such role given your experience.

You could go for Senior roles, but surely it will be harder to land an offer as a Senior right out of University.

> Should i put 3 years experience in my resume?

That would depend on the role you seek to apply to.

If it's full stack, and you have, say 2 years on it, specify it that way. If it's home automation, and you have 1 year experience on it, that is what you should include on your resume.

If it's something different, that you don't have experience on, then it would be unprofessional to mention you have experience on the matter.

Whatever you decide, focus on the experience that relates most to the job. You can also include other relevant or interesting experience you have (as it would be your first "official" job with a degree), but it would be best to highlight those that relate more strongly to the role you seek.

Comment: I agree with you, one problem i have when i say "i have experience in web dev", usually the contractor says "its just an internship".  How should i respond to it?

Comment: @Paul well, internship experience is valid and real experience IMO (in fact, the whole point of internships is to get experience). If a recruiter or interviewer thinks that internship experience is not relevant or not real experience I would seriously doubt that recruiter's knowledge. If that is the case, I would also think twice if that company is a place where I would want to work. Have in mind that saying "it's just an internship" could be a technique to have an "argument" to pay you less. Be careful with that, but also have in mind that seeking for a senior role could be unrealistic.

Comment: @darkcyganus i agree. I fell more capaciteded then the full time employees at my company, but i cant get a better offer atm - imo it because im taking 2 classes on the university, so i cant be on the company for 8 straight hours

Comment: @Paul but... to answer your actual question (how should you respond). I would expose what you have learned during that internship, and how that knowledge will bring benefit to the company.

Comment: When we have interns, we give them projects and have them work in our environment.  They get familiar with the scrum-based process we use, the use of version control, code reviews, and have their code reviewed by experienced people.  I'd call that valuable experience just on its own.

Comment: @DavidThornley totally agree with that.

Comment: @davidthornly on my own projects i use git, scrum and other tools commonly on it world. But in any company i worked, it was use. I work for an it company that dont use git. Its so strange. On interviews, I usually expose it "i use it on my own time, not on the company"

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing to do would be to give a brief description of your experiences and their duration on your resume. As for applying, go for anything you think you are capable of. No one is going to blacklist you because they wanted 3 years of hard production experience and you only had internship experience. Resume is largely just to get to the next stage of the interview process.

Answer (score 0):

I've interviewed and hired literally dozens  of persons over my career, either as full-time, contractors and interns. In all cases, interns actual-experience was easy to prove with technical questions and puzzles.

I found that many of my recently hired interns happen to be brilliant and had just as much experience as a 3-years full time developer. In those cases, when hiring the intern for full time job, I would always seek to hire them as Senior, since I believe you should be paid for what you know and do, regardless of the time it took you to master it.

On another hand, I was always strict with interns with the promise that they would land a job doubling their current salary  either with my employer (I wished for it), or other employer (if my employer was fool enough to let them go), within a year of experience under my wing. The whole point was that in one year they could match the knowledge of an experienced developer, by mentoring constantly and making them upgrade themselves every month.

So, honestly, it will depends a lot on whose on the other side of the table during the negociation. Just make sure it's clear to them your knowledge level and maturity (not just in paper: prove it).

Another power tip: some companies assign job grades to new hires merely based on their current salary and not on actual knowledge (example, if you make 60K per year and they offer you 90K per year, 50% raise, they will assign you the grade on which 90K fits in). However, there are companies whom, if you were already an intern in that company, they hire you directly as "experienced" (not junior) per policy. So, DO RESEARCH about the companies you apply to and find out how they do things, so you can be prepared.